# How can I disable Cron jobs from Windows?

Tags: cron

My friend thought it would be funny to make a Cron job on my pi that made it shutdown every minute, so now it boots and immediately shuts down. Can I delete the file with the Cron job from a windows computer or will I have to just wipe my SD and start fresh?

Comment: You want to access the linux partition on the SD card in windows, is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the 3rd Party software on Windows. Something like Ext2Fsd or [Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)

Comment: @Hector If that solves the problem ,  mark the answer as accepted.